# iAmConfigurable in abstract base class to have configurable options of any type in derived class

Tags: c#, generics, interface, abstract

What I want is a class that can have configurable properties/variables of any type.
And that the way of setting and getting these configurations are defined in an interface.
It will become some kind of plugin architecture. And each plugin has its own configurable parameters of unknonwn type (let it be a string, double, int, whatever). The user will be able to set these in the GUI, and these will be stored in a database by the host application of the plugin.

The problem is, how I do not know how to achieve this form of abstraction when settings these configurations of any type. It would be nice if it would not be necessary to cast `Object` to e.g. a `double` when configuring the class.

I have this `pseudo` code to make myself more clear, see below.

```
public class Configurable<T>
{
    string Name;
    T Value;
    string Description;
}

public interface iAmConfigurable
{
    void Set(Configurable<T>);
    Configurable<T> Get(string name);
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass : iAmConfigurable
{
    public abstract void Set(Configurable<T>);
    public abstract Configurable<T> Get(string name);
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    Configurable<int> MinimumSlope = new Configurable<int>
    {
        Name = "MinimumSlope",
        Value = 20,
        Description = "The lowest the slope of the trend may get before triggering the alarm"
    }

    public abstract void Set(string name, T value)
    {
        if(name == "MinimumSlope") MinimumSlope.Value = value;
    }

    public abstract Configurable<T> Get(string name)
    {
        if(name == "MinimumSlope") return MinimumSlope;
    }
}
```